# Javascript How to get all values for a property from an Array of Objects?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, filter, properties

Hello fellow Javascript developers, I hope you're all having a good day.

I'm trying to get all dynamically set values for certain properties of object elements from an array for my filter. For e.g.

```
var data = [
    {id: 0, category: "RINGS", type: "CH"},
    {id: 1, category: "NECKLACE", type: "CHE"},
    {id: 2, category: "PENDANT", type: "CH"},
    {id: 3, category: "BRACELET", type: "CH"},
    {id: 4, category: "RINGS", type: "HBR"},
    {id: 5, category: "PENDANT", type: "CHE"},
  ];
```

and exmaple array for how my data comes from the api. As you can see the two properties `category` & `type` that I know will always remain constant but their values may change based on user input data.

I want to set all available values for these two object props for my filter. How do I get all the values for a certain prop to get myself an array of values for a certain property which then I can assign to my Dropdown in React Native.

Result:

```
var category = [
    { name: "Rings", id: "RINGS"},
    { name: "Necklace", id: "NECKLACE"},
    { name: "Pendant", id: "PENDANT"},
    { name: "Bracelet", id: "BRACELET"},
  ]
```

and

```
var type = [
    { name: "CH", id: "CH" },
    { name: "CHE", id: "CHE" },
    { name: "HBR", id: "HBR" },
  ]
```

and then these two arrays are basically passed to the filter which will then be used to sort the data. I assume it's not too complex, but I'm a total beginner in javascript so bear with me. Thank You.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
var data = [
  { id: 0, category: 'RINGS', type: 'CH' },
  { id: 1, category: 'NECKLACE', type: 'CHE' },
  { id: 2, category: 'PENDANT', type: 'CH' },
  { id: 3, category: 'BRACELET', type: 'CH' },
  { id: 4, category: 'RINGS', type: 'HBR' },
  { id: 5, category: 'PENDANT', type: 'CHE' }
];

const categories = [], types = [];
data.forEach((item) => {
  if (!categories.includes(item.category)) {
    categories.push(item.category);
  }
  if (!types.includes(item.type)) {
    types.push(item.type);
  }
});

const category = categories.map((item) => ({
  name: item.toLowerCase(),
  id: item
}));
const type = types.map((item) => ({ name: item, id: item }));

console.log(category);
console.log(type);
```

Answer (score -1):

There are atleast 2 ways you can do this:

1. Using `Array.includes`. As @baymax mentioned above, you can filter through the array using `includes`.
2. Using `Set` in Javascript. Check out the code.

```js
const data = [
    {id: 0, category: "RINGS", type: "CH"},
    {id: 1, category: "NECKLACE", type: "CHE"},
    {id: 2, category: "PENDANT", type: "CH"},
    {id: 3, category: "BRACELET", type: "CH"},
    {id: 4, category: "RINGS", type: "HBR"},
    {id: 5, category: "PENDANT", type: "CHE"},
  ];

// by includes
const uniqueCategories = [];
const uniqueTypes = []
data.forEach(entry => {
  if (!uniqueCategories.includes(entry.category)){
     uniqueCategories.push(entry.category)
  }
  if (!uniqueTypes.includes(entry.type)){
     uniqueTypes.push(entry.type)
  }
})

const categoriesMap = uniqueCategories.map(category => ({name: category.toLowerCase(), id: category}));
const typesMap = uniqueTypes.map(typeEntry => ({name: typeEntry, id: typeEntry}));

// by set
const categoriesSet = new Set()
const typesSet = new Set()

data.forEach(entry => {
  categoriesSet.add(entry.category);
  typesSet.add(entry.type);
});

const uniqueCategoriesFromSet = Array.from(categoriesSet).map(category => ({name: category.toLowerCase(), id: category}));
const uniqueTypesFromSet = Array.from(typesSet).map(typeEntry => ({name: typeEntry, id: typeEntry}));

console.log(uniqueCategoriesFromSet, uniqueTypesFromSet);

console.log(categoriesMap, typesMap)
```